# Replacing http https with anchor link in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using the below method to replace in my description if it has any text with http /https with a link with a class disableUrl and rel=nofollow to it.
As my description has some image also like `<img src="https://assests/..."/>` , the image src also gets changed to

```
<img src="<a class='disableUrl' rel='nofollow'>https://assests/...</a>"/>
```

Below is the replacePattern i have used.

```
replacePattern = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim
replacedText = content.replace(replacePattern, "<a class='disableUrl' rel='nofollow'>$1</a>")
```

Suggest me in restricting images not to generate anchor link inside image tag

EDIT

Description contains the text with all tags with all sort of data. even image tag with src with https://

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Can't you just have the server output "//assets/..." and there is no need to worry about http or https?

Comment: Why not just select the `a` elements, and work on just those, instead of everything: `$('a').each(function(){ // do regex/replace stuff in here, on the 'this' node, where it can't affect images });`

Comment: @David Thomas - My description has https without inside anchor tag also , so i have to fully take the whole description and have to generate link for https with rel=nofollow and class=disableUrl which disable the url.

Comment: @DavidThomas - Description has links as text also, which i need to convert tat to anchor tag with class and rel. Thats the reason i am taking the whole content